# How to estimate the DNA density in human sperm head?

Tags: cell-biology, homework, biophysics

I have got an estimate of sperm head volume from internet.Like consider it as a disk of order 4-5µm. Now I wanted to find the DNA density in the sperm head. How to find that?

Comment: I don't understand what the value 4-5 microns refers to. If it is supposed to be a volume it should have units of volume.

Comment: figure out if 4-5 um refers to the diameter or radius, then calculate the volume of the sperm head, then figure out the volume of a chromosome, assume it as cylindrical and then figure for 23 chromosomes how much space is filled hence you would know the density

Comment: @Bez I assume the aim is to get pg per um3 or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Find, or calculate, a value for the volume of the sperm head.

Find a value for the size of the human genome (haploid or diploid?)

Convert the genome size, which will probably in Giga basepairs, into mass (I suggest picograms).

Divide mass by volume to get a density, pg μm<sup>-3</sup>

Refinement - does the sperm nucleus take up all of the head volume? Do you need to factor this in?